# Get inviter for an event in facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

I have an application and I obtain the list of events for the current logged in user.

I can get the **creator** of the event but I just can't figure out how can I obtain the user who **invited** me to a certain event.

Sometimes the creator is not the same as the inviter. Already attending guests can invite other people.

Can I get this info using the facebook API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question and nice-to-have feature but I think the actual Facebook API doesn't allow you to get that information.

The information you can get, about an event:

Graph API: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

FQL: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/

You could eventually use a "trick" like opening the event page in an iFrame or a popup. Then, with javascript or jQuery get the html contents of that iframe/popup and then get the part that says "FriendName invited you". FriendName = First and last name (+link to profile) of the inviter... It's a dirty solution and probably facebook has some security checks that won't allow this, but maybe it works, let me know ;)

Comment: did somebody try the "dirty solution"? curious to know what you used... javascript? or server download with credentials? if server side I'm curious to get some details such how to give the credentials to the server etc. thx for sharing

Answer (score 2):

Facebook added a new feature which will achieve what you are looking for. Event_Member's "Inviter" in Facebook's FQL will show you who the inviter is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FQL for that like:

```
SELECT inviter FROM event_member WHERE eid=146509188851970 AND uid=me()
```

You can see the example here:

[Graph Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/465440490160635/?fql=SELECT%20inviter%20FROM%20event_member%20WHERE%20eid=146509188851970%20AND%20uid=me%28%29%20)

Just remember to change the id of the event.